# Android- Calculate price from the menu in restaurant menu

Tags: android, menu

I want to implement this :
Display menus (this can be any type of menus, there should be price and 
quantity choice associated with each menu item. display the price for each menu item.
I was able to display menus but don't know how to calculate price of menu items ?
Thanks

Comment: where you display menu textview or button or what? and when you want to do calculation after selecting menu or clicking a button? clarify your question

Comment: the user will select the items that are displayed in the menu along with their price. And then after clicking a button the total price will be displayed of the items that were selected by the user.

Comment: `in the menu` do you mean context menu??? or a listview or a expandable listview or what???

Comment: context menu .. sorry for not clearing the question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get info from menu like below

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
     int listPosition = info.position;
     price= myList.get(listPosition).getPrice();//list item price
     quantity=myList.get(listPosition).getQuantity();//list item quantity

     result=price*quantity;
}
```

Here `myList` is the arraylist from where the menu was inflated. Use required variable type where needed.